# .net Core - Ajax doesnt get data on Server but working on my local

Tags: jquery, ajax, ubuntu, asp.net-core

My Ajax Codes working on local but Doesnt get data on Ubuntu server

I think there is problem on dates. 
Because Code working when there is no date.
I dont know how look and how make Ubuntu server dates settings.

My Ajax Codes :

```
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: '/Statisti/UrunCikisIcin',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'Adi': Adi,
                'OcakUrun': Cinsi,
            },

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(".HorizontalChart").hide();
                $(".HorizontalChartuc").hide();
                for (var i = 0; i < OcakList.length; i++) {
                    OcakList[i].destroy();
                }
                OcakList = [];

                if (Cinsi == "urun") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        ClickUrunMiktarAdi.push(data[i].nOcak.neredekiOcak);
                        ClickUrunMiktarSayisi.push(data[i].sayi);

                    }
                    basliktxt = data[0].nOcak.uadi;
                } else {

                    for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
                        ClickUrunMiktarAdi.push(data[k].nOcak.uadi);
                        ClickUrunMiktarSayisi.push(data[k].sayi);
                    }
                    basliktxt = data[0].nOcak.neredekiOcak;
                }


                var ctx = document.getElementById("ikinci-bar-chart").getContext("2d");

                OcakList.push(new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: ClickUrunMiktarAdi, //["Su", "Çay", "Tost", "Albeni", "Soda", "Bisküvi"],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "Yapılan",
                            backgroundColor: Renkler,
                            data: ClickUrunMiktarSayisi, // [2478, 5267, 734, 784, 433, 123, 22, 111, 567, 22]
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        legend: { display: false },
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: basliktxt
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            mode: 'index',
                            intersect: false,
                        },
                        hover: {
                            mode: 'nearest',
                            intersect: true
                        },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    min: 0
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }));

                ClickUrunMiktarAdi = [];
                ClickUrunMiktarSayisi = [];


            }

        });
```

My Controller Codes:

```
public ActionResult UrunCikisIcin(string Adi, string OcakUrun)
        {

            //var bugun = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
            //var otuzgunonce = bugun.AddDays(-30);

            var FromTarih = HttpContext.Session.GetString("dateFrom");
            var ToTarih = HttpContext.Session.GetString("dateTo");
            var otuzgunonce = Convert.ToDateTime(FromTarih);
            var bugun = Convert.ToDateTime(ToTarih);

            if (OcakUrun == "urun")
            {
                var reply = _context.UrunCikis
                    .Include(u => u.CıkısOcakNavigation)
                    .Include(k => k.Urun).Where(u => u.AktifPasif && u.Tarih >= otuzgunonce && u.Tarih <= bugun && u.Urun.AktifPasif)
                    .Where(s => s.Urun.Uadi == Adi)
                    .GroupBy(u => new { u.CıkısOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak, u.Urun.Uadi })
                    .Select(u => new { NOcak = u.Key, Sayi = u.Sum(k => k.UrunSayisi)
                    }).ToList();

                return Json(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                var reply = _context.UrunCikis
                    .Include(u => u.CıkısOcakNavigation)
                    .Include(k => k.Urun).Where(u => u.AktifPasif && u.Tarih >= otuzgunonce && u.Tarih <= bugun && u.Urun.AktifPasif)
                    .Where(s => s.CıkısOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak == Adi)
                    .GroupBy(u => new { u.CıkısOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak, u.Urun.Uadi })
                    .Select(u => new {
                        NOcak = u.Key,
                        Sayi = u.Sum(k => k.UrunSayisi)
                    }).ToList();
                return Json(reply);
            }
        }
```

It gives an error when I click chart columns:

> (index):670 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nOcak' of undefined
>      at Object.success ((index):670)
>      at u (jquery.min.js:2)
>      at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>      at k (jquery.min.js:2)
>      at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add null check for `basliktxt`

```
            if (Cinsi == "urun") {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    ClickUrunMiktarAdi.push(data[i].nOcak.neredekiOcak);
                    ClickUrunMiktarSayisi.push(data[i].sayi);

                }
                if(data && data.length > 0)
                    basliktxt = data[0].nOcak.uadi;
            } else {

                for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
                    ClickUrunMiktarAdi.push(data[k].nOcak.uadi);
                    ClickUrunMiktarSayisi.push(data[k].sayi);
                }
                if(data && data.length > 0)
                    basliktxt = data[0].nOcak.neredekiOcak;
            }
```

Comment: Yes, data is null but I need receive data.

Comment: if data has array value, it shouldn't throw exception